# Disable checkboxes when another is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC web app, in one section i manage the permission for users (such as decide which information the user can see/edit/add/delete ecc...).

For prevent some errors, if the checkbox in the column Admin is checked the others in the row will be disabled, because the group Admin can do everything, same thing with the Manager column, but in this case only the checkboxes on his right will be disabled.

Afeter many researches, i didn't find anything which can be useful for my case

This is my View code:

```
<body>
<div class="limiter">
    <br />
    <div class="container-table100">
        <div class="wrap-table100">
            <div class="table">
                <table id="tablePermission">
                    @{
                        CEG_dev_labelsEntities db = new 
                        CEG_dev_labelsEntities();
                        int countY = 1;

                        //get all groups
                        var groups = from g in db.Groups
                                     orderby g.group_name
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         g.group_name,
                                         g.group_description
                                     };
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="table100-head">
                                <th class="column1">Username</th>
                                @foreach (var item in groups)
                                {                                                                            
                                  <td><button>@item.group_name</button</td>
                                }
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        foreach (var item in db.Users)
                        {
                            <tbody id="myTable">
                                @{
                                    //get all user's group
                                    var group_list = from g in db.Groups
                                                     join ug in 
                             db.UserGroups on g.id_group equals ug.id_group
                                                 join u in db.Users on 
                                                 ug.id_user equals u.id_user
                                                 where u.username == 
                                                 item.username
                                                 select new
                                                 {
                                                    g.group_name
                                                 };
                                    //save the single values in a list
                                    //so all information are more accesible
                                    List<string> group_user_list = new 
                                    List<string>();
                                    foreach (var item_ug in group_list)
                                    {                                        
                                    group_user_list.Add(item_ug.group_name);
                                    }
                                    <tr style="cursor:default">
                                     <tdclass="column1">
                                      @Html.DisplayFor(model =item.username)
                                     </td>
                                     @foreach (var itemG in groups)
                                     {
                                      //check the corresponding 
                                      //checkbox if user is a member 
                                      //of a specific group                                        
                          if(group_user_list.Contains(itemG.group_name))
                          {
                          <td style="padding-left:80px"><input 
                          type="checkbox"  checked="checked" 
                          class="chkclass" username="@item.username" 
                          groupname="@itemG.group_name" id="@countY" /></td>
                           }
                           else
                           {
                           <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass" 
                               username="@item.username" 
                               groupname="@itemG.group_name" 
                               id="@countY" />
                           </td>
                           }
                           countY++;
                         }
                        </tr>
                        }
                     </tbody>
                        }
                    }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the table:

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciate.

Leo.

EDIT

I have this click event on checkboxes for managing user's permissions

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.chkclass').click(function () {
        var getchkid = $(this).attr('id');
        var isChecked = $('#' + getchkid).is(':checked');
        if ($('#' + getchkid).is(':checked') == true) {
            // to be send to your call
            var username = $(this).attr('username');
            var groupname = $(this).attr('groupname');
            //here put your call ajax to your action
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                url: '/UserGroups/AddPermission',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    'usr': username,
                    'grp': groupname
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#' + getchkid).prop('checked', true);
                },
                error: function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
                    alert('Exception:', exception);
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            if ($('#' + getchkid).is(':checked') == false) {
                // to be send to your call
                var username = $(this).attr('username');
                var groupname = $(this).attr('groupname');
                //here put your call ajax to your action
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'Post',
                    url: '/UserGroups/DeletePermission',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        'usr': username,
                        'grp': groupname
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.error == true) {
                            alert('Error, must be there at least one 
                            admin');
                            $('#' + getchkid).prop('checked', true);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#' + getchkid).prop('checked', false);
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
                        alert('Exception:', exception);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: On a side note, you don't need == true, you can do if($('#' + getchkid).is(':checked')){} and then for if you want false its if(!$('#' + getchkid).is(':checked')){}. Also, if the first statement isn't true then the 2nd has to be false so you don't need to add a statement claiming if it is false, just say else {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing a loop where everything is the same, you could do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/z2mf8314/1/

```
$('.chkclass').click(function () {
  var getchkid = $(this).attr('id');
  var isChecked = $('#' + getchkid).is(':checked');
  var username = $(this).attr('username');
  var groupname = $(this).attr('groupname');
  (getchkid == "1" && isChecked) ? $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not('#1').prop({'disabled': true, 'checked': false }) : $(this).closest('tr').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
  if (isChecked) {
    // to be send to your call
    //here put your call ajax to your action

  }
  else {
    // to be send to your call
    //here put your call ajax to your action

  }
});
```

Comment: Nice, but for me doesn't work probably because i have another click event on the checkboxes, this event add or remove permission to the user

Comment: If thats true then you can just add the code inside to that one and it should work

Comment: I provide my other click event, if you want to take a look

Comment: I added an update with your code in it, it looks like you're using numbers for id's which is why I added a number to the id.

Comment: Yes, i use number so in this way every checkbox is unique, but i want to uncheck them when the page is loaded, not only when user click on them?